# How to remove odd lines except for first line using SED or AWK

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have the following file

```
# header1 header2
zzzz yyyy
1
kkkkk wwww
2
```

What I want to do is to remove odd lines except the header
yielding:

```
# header1 header2
zzzz yyyy
kkkkk wwww
```

I tried this but it removes the header too

```
awk 'NR%2==0'
```

What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works on **GNU sed**

```
sed '3~2d' ip.txt
```

This deletes line numbers starting from 3rd line and then +2,+4,+6, etc

Example:

```
$ seq 10 | sed '3~2d'
1
2
4
6
8
10
```

Comment: That's using an oddball GNU `sed` feature which I'd never found a use for; well done on finding one.

Answer (score 4):

```
awk 'NR==1 || NR%2==0'
```

If the record number is 1 or is even, print it.

```
awk 'NR % 2 == 0 || NR == 1'
```

Reversing the comparisons might be marginally faster.  The difference probably isn't measurable.  (And the choice of spacing is essentially immaterial too.)

Answer (score 2):

You just need

```
awk 'NR==1 || NR%2==0' file
```

- This keeps the header part of the file intact and applies the rule `NR%2==0`, which is true only for even lines(starting from the header) in which case it is printed.

Another variant of the same above answer

```
awk 'NR==1 || !(NR%2)' file
```

- For even lines `(NR%2)` becomes 0 and negation of that becomes a true condition to print the line

Answer (score 2):

```
sed '1!{N;P;d}'
```

`1!` On lines other than the first (the default behavior echoes the first line)
`N` append the next line to the current line
`P` print only the first of the two
`d` delete them both.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '1b;n;d' file
```

But:

```
sed '3~2d' file
```

Is far neater.